# How do I apply the Recipe that I've included on the Run_list in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I've been stuck on this for hours. I have created a new machine and bootstrapped that to my Chef server. I usually use the "-r" parameter to install the recipes right away during the bootstrap process.

However, I want to add a new recipe to an existing machine. I have added a recipe to a run_list of the node using "knife node add"; however, I still haven't figured out a way to apply that new recipe so that the new tool is installed on the node.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

After you have updated a run_list using knife, all you have to do is run

```
chef-client
```

on that bootstrapped machine. Chef Client will connect to Chef Server and will see the new run_list, and will download and apply new recipes accordingly.